# Edit a spreadsheet with Python(passing by CSV file)

Tags: python, csv

I've a spreadsheet with the follow fields:

```
id age smoker do sport
1   35  yes    rare
2   40  no     frequently
3   20  no     never 
4   ..  ..     ..
```

I'd like to create a Python script that edit this spreadsheet passing by csv file conversion.

"yes" become 1 , "no" become 0,"rare" become 0, "frequently" become 1 and "never" become 2.

I've saved a spreadsheet as a csv file, using delimiter as ';' and quotechar ' " '.

Now I've write this code:

```
import csv
filecsv=open("file.csv","r")
reader=csv.reader(filecsv, delimiter= ';' , quotechar=' " ')
out=open("outfile.csv","w")
output=csv.writer(out, delimiter= ';' , quotechar=' " ')

for row in reader:
    for field in row:
        if row[field]=='yes':
                .
                .
                .
                .
```

But I don't know how to continue....

Could someone tell me how  use python to make these changes?

Is it better using a Python list or dictionary?

Thank's to everybody!

Comment: The first answer should be enough. Thanks. If I want to edit line by line How could I do?

Answer (score 2):

Even though CSV files look like spread sheets, at their core they are simply text files. This means you don't actually need to use the csv library but instead read it as a simple string.

Once you have the file as a string you can use regular expressions to convert the relevant values. Here's an example:

```
import re
o = open("output","w")
data = open("file").read()
o.write( re.sub("someword","newword",data) )
o.close()
```

Remember, you will need one `re.sub()` call for each value you wish to convert.

Comment: In general it is probably better to go line by line instead of reading the entire file, unless you know the file is small enough to fit in memory, and that you will never want to run this on bigger files. (usually you can't know that)

Comment: That should be enought. Thank you! If I want to edit line by line, How should I do?

Comment: @bongini.simone you'd simply change `data = open("file").read()` to `f = open("file")` then, just like in your code, go `for line in f:`.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how you already know about Python's [csv library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), it should be trivial to, for each row of the input csv, create a new row with the changes you require, and write it out to a new csv file.

Notice how the csv reader treats each row as a list. Next, look csv writer's [`writerow()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method; it takes a python list and writes it as a csv row. All you need to do is read one row at a time, make the changes you want and spit it back out to the writer. Using your code:

```
for row in reader: #for each row in the input
    outrow = list(row) # make a copy of the row. I'm not sure if you NEED to do this, but it doesn't hurt.

    if outrow[2] == "yes": #if the value in the 3rd column, "smoker", is "yes"
        outrow[2] = 1 #change it to 1
    elif outrow[2] == "no": #if it's "no"
        outrow[2] = 0 #change it to 0.

    #repeat this process for outrow[3] (meaning column #4, "do sport")

    output.writerow(outrow)
```

You probably noticed that python calls the 3rd column 2 and the 4th column 3 This is because python counts starting at 0 (so the 1st column is column 0). You should be able to follow this example to make all the changes that you need.

Don't forget to close your files when you're finished!

Comment: I have already tried to edit line by line..I didn't have success! I don't know how create a list to pass a writerow() method.

Comment: @bongini.simone yes. `output`, the csvwriter you created in your code, has the `writerow()` method. You can use it by calling `output.writerow()`. I updated my answer to give you a cleared idea of what I'm talking about. Also, I apologize: some programming languages use the word "method", some use "function", and some use "subroutine" but they all basically mean the same thing. I forgot which one python used so I am sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

if you will always have that format and you want to replace line by line:

```
replacements_dict = {
  'yes': 1,
  'no' : 0,
  'rare': 0,
  'frequently': 1,
  'never': 2
}

for row_list in reader:
   output.writerow([
     row_list[0], 
     row_list[1]
     replacements_dict[row_list[2]],
     replacements_dict[row_list[3]]
    ])
```

you could also read your csv into memory as a string and just replace the words like georgesl suggest

Comment: This will cause problems if the input has values other than "yes", "no","rare", "frequently", or "never". While I like that your code is succinct, I prefer the longer if-statements because they are a bit easier to read, a bit more robust, and a bit easier to understand for most people.

Comment: also, you're missing a comma after `row_list[1]`, but that isn't a big deal.